# Can I Login to DNN site and not have to log in to a seperate site that uses same UN & PW?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, dotnetnuke

i have developed an online tool that requires authentication. The UN & PW will be the same for all the users as their other ones for the regular site. As of now, if they are running on the DNN site, they must relogin if they go to my site. Is there a way to make it so that they remain logged in?

Thanks for any help. Let me know if you need more information.

For clarification: My site uses the DNN database to authenticate its users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [DNN Single Sign On](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1531/DotNetNuke-A-Single-Sign-on-Solution-C.aspx)?

Comment: I have not, but I will look now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can You try redesign your tool to become DNN module ?

Comment: That was what I initially tried to do. But I had some issues and thought this way might work better, but now I am starting to think that battle might be more easily won. Tomorrow, I will revisit that problem. Thanks for the suggestion.